# Is there a getComponentShape() method for Java Swing/ AWT?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm just stepping into this huge world of designing graphic UIs, so please be patient.

I went through (some of) the (vast) documentation on the official website and I just wanted to know if there was a method that told me the shape of my JComponent.

When I do getBounds it says rectangle, does this refer to my shape?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWT's class `Component` and Swing's class `JComponent` don't have the concept
of arbitrary shapes, they just have a rectangular shape.
That's why `JComponent`'s method `getBounds` returns a [`Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)
which is just a special case of the [`Shape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface.

Only class [`java.awt.Window`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) has [`getShape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getShape--) and [`setShape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setShape-java.awt.Shape-) methods,
and of course all its subclasses (`Dialog`, `Frame`, `JWindow`, `JDialog`, `JFrame`, ...) also have. May be this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Fritsch. A follow up (if you don't mind), I'm trying to modify the shape of a menu. But it inherits from JComponent. Do I have to create a new class that instead inherits from Window then?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `Window` is a *top-level* window, meaning it can resized and moved across the screen by the user with the mouse. But a menu needs to be a *non-top-level* component, being inside of another top-level window. Therefore you can't make the menu a subclass of `Window`.

Comment: Is there any other way I could set the shape of the menu then, since JComponent won't even tell me what shape it is?

Comment: @user7999116 You can write your own menu class (subclass of  `JComponent`, `JMenu` or whatever) and implement its painting yourself.
I suggest you ask a new question for that.